# INSERT to Oracle table from SQL Server database link

Tags: sql-server, oracle, remote-server, gateway

I have created a database link to SQL Server 2012 database in Oracle 11gR2 using the Oracle Gateway for SQL Server. The connection is working fine and I am able to run queries and stored procedure from SQL Server.

The problem arises when I try to retrieve an XML column from SQL Server. Oracle documents clearly states that if database is in UTF character set (AL32UTF8), XML is supported, but in LONG datatype format.

I am able to query the XML column by

```
SET LONG 5000;
select "XMLColumn" FROM "xmltable"@sqlserver;
```

but while trying to insert this into an oracle table with Long datatype it gives the following error.

```
SQL Error: ORA-00997: illegal use of LONG datatype
```

Is there any workaround for this problem.

I even tried to convert the incoming XML to CLOB as suggested by Sanders, which perfectly makes sense. But somehow that too throws back the same error. In below query Name is obviously the XML column from SQL Server.

```
CREATE TABLE TEMPCLOB
AS
SELECT TO_LOB("Name") AS "Name" FROM "xmldata"@sqlserver;
```

Answer (score 0):

LONG is deprecated datatype in Oracle. You can spend time to this problem, but I'd advice you to convert it immediately into CLOB or XMLTYPE and have no problem at all.

Comment: Hello Sanders, you are spot on - LONG is deprecated. But the problem here is that since the datatype is in XML on SQL Server, when we do linked query, Oracle [Gateway](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/gateways.112/e12069/apa.htm#GMSWN400) converts it to LONG automatically. I just want to insert the SQLServer XML to Oracle table (SSIS won't help, as my usage case is different).

Comment: As you said, you can SELECT this XML (converted to LONG) but had met trouble when tried to INSERT it into table. So I'd try to convert this (selected) LONG into CLOB or XMLTYPE and then insert this CLOB/XMLTYPE into table.

Comment: Even when I try to convert the LONG into CLOB or XMLTYPE, it gives me the same error.
     ORA-00997: illegal use of LONG datatype.
 I am not sure whats happening.